# I would like to learn about creating graphic objects at Runtime in c#

Tags: c#, graphics

I would like to learn about creating a program that I could draw simple shapes and be able to select them for editing - like resizing, order of display, color change. Is there an online resource that someone knows of that would help me reach my goals.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sneaky way I used to do it was to create a custom control, remove the background from it and paint my shapes and sizes on it. Then, you can easily implement selection (override OnClick), dragging and resizing (OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove, OnMouseUp). You can then implement options like color, etc. by means of a property (see Browsable attribute and property get/setters) and a PropertyGrid control.

Anything beyond that, though - Bezier curves and such - would need something a tad more advanced, though.

The alternative is to only use such controls for the sizing handles, and do all the drawing on one central canvas - the only drawback then is figuring out how to select a shape on the canvas.

Comment: Unfortunately none that I have handy (at work at the moment), but the basic steps are:

1. Create a custom control
2. Override OnPaint to make it draw what you require
3. Override OnClick method to "select" it
4. Override OnMouseDown/Move/Up to implement dragging

Answer (score 2):

"GDI+" is what you are looking for. You can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0f23z7.aspx